# sharing variables between controller an view in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my controller I am collecting data (into a hash) like this (note that I do not have a `BillingAddress` model in my app, `@billing_address` is standard ruby hash

```
@billing_address = params[:billing_address]
```

my view is laid out like this

```
<%= text_field_tag 'billing_address[phone]' %>
```

I want to show the previous value that user entered (in case of errors), like this:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'billing_address[phone]', @billing_address['phone'] %>
```

however, this gives me an exception saying I am trying to access nil, ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `params[:billing_address]` is `nil`.
Try to assign empty hash if it is.

```
@billing_address = params[:billing_address] || {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the Rails way of showing previous values in case of error. Check this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3) to get idea on how to handle errors better way.